# How to Make A button do more than one action xcode

Tags: ios, button, uibutton, action

Ok So In My Xcode project I Have A button That I need to do the same method twice but with A Different Image Plz Help

Code:

```
UIImage * toImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CharacterBackwards.png"];
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                  duration:0.01f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                animations:^{
                    self->Guy.image = toImage;
                } completion:NULL];

sleep(0.4);
```

Comment: NEVER use `sleep` on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

This is what methods are for. Create a method that takes an image name:

```
- (void)transitionToImage:(NSString *)imageName {
    UIImage * toImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CharacterBackwards.png"];
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                      duration:0.01f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                    animations:^{
                        self->Guy.image = toImage;
                    } completion:NULL];
}
```

Now have your button handler call this twice:

```
- (IBAction)buttonHandler {
    [self transitionToImage:@"CharacterBackwards.png"];
    [self performSelector:@selector(transitionToImage:) withObject:@"CharacterForwards.png" afterDelay:0.4];
}
```

Comment: Where do i place - (void)transitionToImage:(NSString *)imageName {
    UIImage * toImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CharacterBackwards.png"];
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                      duration:0.01f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                    animations:^{
                        self->Guy.image = toImage;
                    } completion:NULL];
}

Comment: Put it in the same class that has your button handler method.

Comment: Im a Newbie But Do i create an (ibaction) for button handler and a (void) for transitionToImage

Comment: Put the code exactly like I have it. Hookup your button to the `buttonHandler` method. Of course feel free to name these two method anything you like.

Comment: So My IbAction is ArrowLeft So I Put [self transitionToImage:@"CharacterBackwards.png"];
    [self performSelector:@selector(transitionToImage:) withObject:@"CharacterForwards.png" afterDelay:0.4]; in there

Comment: @user3528007: @rmaddy is not going to write your app for you.  What you are attempting is very, very easy.  Cut and paste the code supplied and connect the button to the `buttonHandler` method in IB. It will just work but if you are having trouble with this then I suggest you follow a course on iTunesU (e.g. Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad).

Comment: @MinecraftSyntax RobaticCat is correct. What I've pointed out is really basic stuff. If you aren't sure what to do with my answer, I urge you to step back for a bit and find some good tutorials on the Objective-C programming language. Once you get through that, dive into some basic iOS tutorials. You need to learn the basics. This website is not meant to teach you the basics but to help answer specific questions. Good luck.