# How To Make A Button Do An Action Then When I Tap It Again Another Action

Tags: ios, button, uibutton, action

Ok So In My Xcode project I Have A button That I need to do the same Action twice but with A Different Image Plz Help

Code: 
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
    Guy.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

```
UIImage * toImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CharacterBackwards.png"];
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                  duration:0.01f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                animations:^{
                    self->Guy.image = toImage;
                } completion:NULL];
```

Comment: This is basically the same as your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037891/how-to-make-a-button-do-more-than-one-action-xcode). Do not repeat your questions. Just because you don't understand a clear answer given to you in the earlier question is no reason to ask it again.

Answer (score -1):

Try adopting this pseudo code

```
var firstCall = true

function action() {
    if (firstCall) {
        do_action_x()
        firstCall = false
    } else {
        do_action_y()
    }
}
```

Basically just make use of a variable that has different values during the same function call.

Comment: it says undeclared definition of var @AuthorOfTheSurf **Plz Help**

Comment: @MinecraftSyntax It's pseudo code. You can't just copy-paste it.

Comment: Hi MS, the code I posted resembles Javascript, you will need to adapt it to ObjC (which I am not to practiced on).  I believe the first line will be
    BOOL firstCall = YES
Do look up variable declarations and conditional statement syntax in ObjC and slowly it will become second nature

Comment: @AuthorOfTheSurf Just a thought but it's not too useful to post an answer like this. The OP doesn't seem to understand programming basics yet and posting an answer with some high level pseudo code isn't going to help this person at all. It would be best to either delete the answer or provide a more detailed one in the proper language for the question (Objetcive-C).